# Loading static .xml file in a @Service class in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, service, resources, classpath, configuration-files

I'm planning to do few things in my Spring MVC app.

1. Load a static .xml file with configuration in my `ConfigFactory` class with `@Service` annotation.
2. Do some parsing and create instance of a `Configuration` class.
3. Pass this `Configuration` class to `AnotherServiceClass` which will create a `model` that I want later pass to the `view`.

This static file is located in 'WEB-INF/config/sampleItem.xml` location.

When I try to do **the first step** in my @Controller `ItemController` I don't have any problems with that because I have access there to `ServletContext`:

```
 @Autowired ServletContext servletContext;

 public ModelAndView method(){
     File xmlFile = new File(servletContext.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/config/sampleItem.xml"));
     Document config = new SAXBuilder(XMLReaders.NONVALIDATING).build(xmlFile);
     ...
 }
```

But I don't know how to achieve it in my `@Service classes`. When I've tried @Autowiring `ServletContext` in my `ConfigurationFactory` and loading XML in it's constructor again with the same:

```
File xmlFile = new File(servletContext.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/config/sampleItem.xml"));
```

I ended up with an exception:

```
Error creating bean with name 'itemController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.package.service.configuration.ConfigFactory org.package.controller.ItemController.configFactory; (...)
```

Comment: Are you able to re-locate the static file to the classpath that the `ConfigurationFactory` lives on (`WEB-INF/classes` or within the .jar if bundled in a separate .jar? That way you wouldn't be dependent on the real file path, and you could do a `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/config/sampleItem.xml")` inside your `ConfigurationFactory`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Indeed, moving it to the classpath and using `ClassPathResource` solved the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I manage to solve this problem by moving my static xml into `src/main/resources` and by loading it in my `Service` class without using `ServletContext` with :

```
Resource myData = new ClassPathResource("sampleItem.xml");
File xmlFile = myData.getFile();
```